# Circuit for math game grid?

Tags: circuit-design, math

I am a graduate math student and I want to design some electrical circuits for a math games workshop. I know physics only at a high-school level.
At first, let's explain the game and its rules, 
suppose that we have a \$3 \times 3\$ board, 
and there is a light on each square, 
when we press the corresponding switch of each light, 
the status of **that light** and **all other adjacent lights** will change. 
For example, let's consider this example: 
[image]

If we press the corresponding switch of the blue signed square, then the status of the blue signed square and all red signed squares will change. 
At the next step,
if we press the corresponding switch of the pink signed square, then the status of the pink signed square and all orange signed squares will change.

How should I design such a circuit?

---

---

We want to replace the \$3 \times 3\$ board, with other boards like: 
[image]

But the rules are the same as the above example.

> How should I design the circuits corresponding to 
>   \$(4 \times 4)\$ or \$(\star \star \star)\$?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a discrete logic circuit or is a solution using a microcontroller appropriate as well?

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic on _any_ site. I've flagged this as "too broad", because I can't see how we can explain this to someone without any circuit experience. Maybe if you can tell us what you have previously constructed, or if you can add some details about how you would like to start.

Comment: As the number of squares can be rather large, I would recommended using a standard tablet with touch screen. Which means it become a software problem. I agree with 'too broad'. (You would probably end-up designing some very similar to a table).

Comment: And what would happen if you pressed the red middle square button or any other button? Your problem is not well-defined - YOU need to define it and write down an algorithm that describes all the effects from all the causes. Can you do this?

Comment: @Andyaka , My dear Andy, as I have explained before every switch changes the status of the corresponding light and all the **adjacent** lights. Also, I've edited my question, such that it contains this special case, you have asked for.

Comment: You mention purple when you might mean pink. Use D type latches and exclusive or gates.

Comment: Define your algorithm, define the state changes, define a state-transition matrix (just to formalize the behavior), then decide if you want the immense labor of a customer TTL or CMOS state machine on VECTOR board, or a MCU implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual circuit is just a microcontroller reading a bunch of switches and controlling a bunch of lights.

You could get a microcontroller with lots of pins, or use I/O expanders, and wire each light and switch to its own pin.  Or, you can do something called *multiplexing*.  The switches and lights would be arranged in a grid.  The microcontroller scans the array as needed.  This is how any similar professionally designed product would likely work.  However, especially if you are new to micros, giving each switch and light its own dedicated pin (possibly thru I/O expanders) will be easier.  For a one-off, that would be fine.

There is another approach that is more complicated electrically, but conceptually simpler.  Use a tiny microcontroller for each square.  The micro has connections to its 4 neighbors.  When a micro detects its button pressed, it complements its light and sends a blip to its neighbors.  When the micro sees a blip from a neighbor, it complements its light.

This makes the firmware in each micro very simple, and only requires 6 I/O connections.  These are 1 for the light, 1 for the button, and 4 lines to each of its neighbors.  The neighbor lines would be passively pulled up, and a micro pulls down on them for some minimum time (a few µs) to indicate a toggle.

Don't forget to debounce the switch input.

Once you have this basic building block, you replicate it to make whatever size array you want.  This system is scalable to large arrays.

The rest is firmware.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you start by researching Mealey state machines. By turning your game into a sate machine, you will be able to easily create your circuit out of digital logic gates. If you want to go a step further you could use an FPGA and a hardware description language like Verilog to design your circuit. However, this requires an understanding of digital logic, state machines and of course how to use a language like Verilog. It may seem like overkill for such a simple task, but it will allow you to easily incorporate the logic of your game for literally any board configuration your FPGA has enough pins for.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a single small PC board for each button that contains logic like that shown below.  The board receives inputs (and ground) from the adjacent switches that toggles a flip flop whenever the switch on an adjacent board or on the board itself is activated.  The switches must be debounced before driving the flip flop clock so that it toggles only once per switch press.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIHSbL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can use a [74HC4075 triple three input OR gate](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4075.pdf) for the OR gates.  You can use a [74HC74 style D flip flop](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc74.pdf) and have an RC based reset drive the reset input to clear all the FFs at power up.  To create a flip flop that toggles for each clock from a D flip flop, feed back the inverted output to the D input as shown below.

[image: toggle flip flop]

(From http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Digital/dig53.php )